Cohabitation of Wild & Domestic Rabbits
I rescued two cottontail rabbits 5 months ago, a friend was putting them into a trash bag to throw away. This last week one rabbit escaped a newly purchased rabbit cage and my dog killed it. I am thinking to free the remainder rabbit and or purchasing a domestic rabbit to provide some social possibility for the remainder rabbit? Will wild befriend a domesticated rabbit?
